# How to filter ListView by something else then CharSequence?

Tags: android

I'm writing custom `BaseAdapter` (backed by `Set`), and I need to filter the data by something other then `CharSequence` (price range, color, etc.).

I looked at [`Filterable`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Filterable.html) interface and [`Filter`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Filter.html) class, but all the methods from `Filter` uses `CharSequence`s.

So, how to do that? Should I encode the filter parameters to `CharSequence` (as JSON, maybe?), or is there some better way?

Also, what's the [`convertResultToString`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Filter.html#convertResultToString(java.lang.Object)) method good for? Because I don't need the result to be `String`, but `Object` from `Set`, because I'm displaying more information then just a `String`.

Comment: What do you mean by filter?

Comment: Something like "Objects that are bluen and green" or "Users that are older then 30".

Comment: I you want to sort the list according to your values in objects and display, check my answer.

Comment: No, I don't care about order of results. (Well, I do, bot it's already implemented.)

I mean pretty much anything which could be in `WHERE` clause of some SQL query. (But the parameters will be hardcoded, so Idon't need to have something this generic)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you implements `Filterable` and `Filter` and, since your adapter is backed by a set of elements, you just can ignore the `CharSequences` in the `public FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence prefix)` method. Inside your adapter, make a copy of your set of elements, which will be the one you'll use to fill the `ListView` or whatever you were using.

After that, inside the `performFiltering(...)` method just remove the elements by your choosen criteria:

```
private class ClientsFilter extends Filter {

        @Override
        public FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence prefix) {

            // Thats the result of our filtering process
            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

            synchronized (mLock) {

                // It's a good idea to work with a copy of the original set of elements, so we can reuse it every time we want to filter
                ArrayList<Client> filteredClients = new ArrayList<>(originalClients); 

                    for (int i = 0; i < filteredClient.size(); i++) {
                        if (// !fit my criteria) {
                            // We remove the clients that doesn`t fit the criteria, so only the good ones stay here
                            filteredClients.remove(i);
                            i--;
                        }
                    }

                results.values = filteredClients;
                results.count = filteredClients.size();
            }

            return results;

        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence prefix, FilterResults results) {
            // And we use the filtered clients in our ListView, GridView or whatever
            listViewClients= (ArrayList<Client>) results.values;
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
```

Some tips:

- Don't forget to use the `synchronized` stuff, or you'll have some funny errors (NPE without any visible reason caused by race conditions)
- Using `Filterable` the filtering process is doing in background, so UI keeps responsive
- Call the `adapter.getFilter().filter()` method when you want to filter your results, like for example when writing in an `EditText`

Comment: Do I have to call `adapter.getFilter().filter()` every time the client's list gets updated (eg. received new clients from server)?

Comment: Usually not, you shouldn't. You only should call `adapter.getFilter().filter()` when the user filters (like choosing an option in a `spinner`, writing something in a filtering field, etc.). You should instead call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` if you update the set, anyway.

Comment: Well, in my code, `notifyDataSetChanged()` doesn't work, but calling `getFilter().filter(null)` after adding new items does.

Answer (score 1):

You can filter as you want but it's required to write some code.

1. In your adapter, create another field for your set. It will be the set you actually display. That mean that in all your `getCount`, `getView`, `getItemId`, `getItem` methods you should use this second set (in fact evrywhere in your adapter). By default, it should be the same as you primary set of data. Your primary set of data will be `mSet` and the display `mDisplaySet`.
2. Create a custom filter method. This method, will filter put in your second set (the one you actually display) the element of your first set that match the given condition :

   ```
   public void filter(Object condition) {
       mDisplaySet = new Set<>();
       for (Object object : mSet) {
           if (object.match(condition) {
               mDisplaySet.add(object);
           }
       }
       notifyDataSetChanged();
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

I looked detail at your questions and I will answer 1 by 1.

**1. So, how to do that? Should I encode the filter parameters to CharSequence (as JSON, maybe?), or is there some better way?** 

I think you should not encode it, just do it as below:

```
public class YourFilterObject { 
    String test1;
    int test2;
}
private YourFilterObject yourFilterObject;
public TestAdapter setFilterObject(YourFilterObject object) {
    this.yourFilterObject = object;
    return this;
}
@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    return new Filter() {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence charSequence) {
            // use yourFilterObject here to filter your adapter
            return null;
        }
        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence charSequence, FilterResults filterResults) {
        }
    };
}
```

Whenever you want to filter your adapter with custom parameters (not just string), you can call call `YourAdapter.setFilterObject(object).getFilter().filter(null);`

**2. what's the convertResultToString method good for**

 Actually this method I use only for `AutocompleteTextView`. When you type something (example: name...) in `AutocompleteTextView`, it will show you a list of object in `filterResults` to choose. When you pick up a result object, the `convertResultToString` function will be called to get the `Text` to be set (show) in `AutocompleteTextView`. If you dont override this method, after picking an object, the `AutocompleteTextView` will show nothing.

Hope this help.